# Evaluating $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\cos x^3\sin x^2dx$ without the Airy function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

$$\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }\cos x^3\sin x^2dx$$
I solved this problem using the special "Airy function". Question: is it possible to solve it in another way?
$$\begin{align}
\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }\cos x^3\sin x^2dx&=\frac{1}{3^{1/3}}\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }\cos \frac{t^3}{3}\sin 3^{-2/3}t^2dt \\[1ex]
&=\frac{1}{3^{1/3}}\Im \int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }\exp \left \{ i\left [ \frac{t^3}{3}+3^{-2/3}t^2 \right ] \right \}dt \\[1ex]
&=\frac{1}{3^{1/3}}\Im \left \{ 2\pi \exp \left \{ 3^{-2/3}i\left [ \frac{2}{3}\left ( 3^{-2/3} \right )^2 \right ] \right \}\operatorname{Ai}\left ( 0-\left [ 3^{-2/3} \right ]^2 \right ) \right \} \\[1ex]
&=\frac{2\pi}{3^{1/3}}\sin \frac{2}{27}\cdot \operatorname{Ai}\left ( -3^{-4/3} \right )
\end{align}$$

Comment: modified bessels or hypergeometric functions should be other options. Once you're in the realm of special functions there are many connections to be made to others. But this is unlikely to become "non-special". Also just a note, I find your notation ambiguous. You intend $\cos x y = \cos(x y)$ in some contexts and $\cos x y = \cos(x)y$ in others.